# How to create a mirrored copy of selected linked meshes?

Tags: mesh, mirror

I have a log house see the image:

[image]

all small logs are linked duplicates of the first small log (second from the bottom).

How do I create a mirrored (across ZY plane) copy of the wall (including all logs big and small), so that the new logs will be linked duplicates of their counterparts?

Ideally, the second log from the bottom still being the only origin of all small logs which are linked duplicates and the big one creating a linked duplicate?

EDIT:

Moving origins doesn't work for me, this is what I get (I do check options/transform/affect only origins):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Your cylinders have all different sizes and all have not applied the scale.

So here is the working solution for you:

Add an empty in the middle and use that empty as mirror object:

[image]

---

old answer:

you can use the mirror modifier, if you change the pivot points of your objects before, like this:

[image]

Comment: I can't move origins with the same effect as in your image, please see update

Comment: Pls provide blend file, I show you then

Comment: https://github.com/alikim-com/blender/blob/main/home_test.blend

Comment: My blender version is 2.90.1

Comment: i updated my answer, thx for the blend file

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!